# Flutter (iOS): the initial firebase dynamic link is not handled on the first installation from TestFlight or in release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have installed firebase dynamic links in my Flutter app, configured it on iOS native side with adding `GoogleService-Info.plist` for every env, have set DYNAMIC_URL and in general all dynamic links work good.

Except only one case: for ONLY FIRST RUN in release mode (or from TestFlight) `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()` returns null.

I install the app on real device in release mode, I don't open it automatically from IDLE, I am scanning  dynamic link QR from camera or clicking on it itself - FIRST TIME app doesn't handle the link and this is the issue! Every next time app is able to handle the link properly from completely closed state (when it's running in a background it every time works with `onLink`).

I tried delays for function start, checked all that code, asked colleagues - freaking nightmare

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post a solution...

I found a way around to resolve this issue:

```
final clipboardData = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
if (clipboardData?.text != null) {
  final uri = Uri.tryParse(clipboardData!.text!);
  if (uri != null) {
     final link = uri.queryParameters['link'];
     if (link != null) {
        final linkUri = Uri.tryParse(link);
        if (linkUri != null) {
           await _handleDeepLink(linkUri);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I use it on first run if initial link is null.

Ugly, but works